# How to communicate with a HTTP/HTTPS server via Python sockets?

Tags: python, sockets, http, https, proxy

I'm trying to create a TCP socket server in Python that after receiving a string of bytes from a client passes the received data(without knowing what it's actually inside, assuming it's a valid HTTP request) to a HTTP or HTTPS proxy and waits for results, my code looks like this:

```
import socket

def test(host, port):
   sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   sock.connect((socket.gethostbyname(host), int(port))

   msg = """GET / HTTP/1.1 
   Host: www.bing.com    
   User-Agent: Firefox

   """

  sent_count = sock.send(msg)
  recv_value = sock.recv(2048)
  print('recvieved:',)
  print str(recv_value)
  pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
   test(host='x.x.x.xx', port='80') # a https proxy server
   test(host='yy.yy.yy.yy', port='80') # a http proxy server
```

But when i connect to the HTTP proxy server it returns something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

And when i connect to the HTTPS proxy server it shows something like:

```
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
```

So wanted to ask if anybody know how could i send HTTP requests to HTTP/HTTPS servers via sockets in Python? or how can i redirect arbitrary strings of data toward HTTP/HTTPS proxy servers in general in Python using sockets?, any suggestions are very much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any good reason of why you are trying to communicate with HTTP server via raw socket?

Comment: I'm thinking of redirecting HTTP requests sent to a port of localhost toward a HTTP or HTTPS proxy server without the need for opening or parsing the string containing the actual request, if it's possible at all.

Comment: It looks that you are trying to create TCP proxy, then it may be a good idea to check existent solutions, like http://voorloopnul.com/blog/a-python-proxy-in-less-than-100-lines-of-code/

Comment: Thanks Vader, but I just want to redirect whatever comes to a port of my machine toward a list of proxy servers that I've got(depending on some circumstances) in Python. I've got no intention of creating my own (full-fledged) proxy server.

Comment: This is exactly what the proxy from the link above does - it receives raw TCP traffic on one address\port and redirects it to another one.

Comment: Just tried your solution by sending the msg to port 9090 of my machine after running proxy.py and it printed:                                                ('recvieved:',)
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Server: squid/2.7.STABLE5
Date: Mon, 01 Jun 2015 19:02:41 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 1185
X-Squid-Error: ERR_INVALID_REQ 0
X-Cache: MISS from DXT-AH-YOUKU-103
X-Cache-Lookup: NONE from DXT-AH-YOUKU-103:80
Via: 1.0 DXT-AH-YOUKU-103:80 (squid/2.7.STABLE5)
Connection: close

Comment: Does it work correctly if you send the same message directly to the upstream proxy?

Comment: No it prints the same results, the proxy the data is being forwarded to is an HTTPS proxy server btw.

Comment: I think it would be better to get it working without proxy in the middle and without SSL first, and only then add proxy and SSL.

Comment: i think you're right